# FlutterでAndroid Studioからスマホで起動するとorg.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserExceptionというエラーが起こる

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

現在Flutterの環境構築をしているのですが、USB接続したスマホ（SCL22）でデフォルトのプロジェクトを起動しようとすると、以下のようなエラーが起こります。

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17871): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lamrongol.date_interval_logger/lamrongol.date_interval_logger.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3752)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1818)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.getSplashScreenFromManifest(FlutterActivity.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.provideSplashScreen(FlutterActivity.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:518)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17871): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3736)
E/AndroidRuntime(17871):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19382): Process: lamrongol.date_interval_logger, PID: 19382
E/AndroidRuntime(19382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lamrongol.date_interval_logger/lamrongol.date_interval_logger.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3752)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1818)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.getSplashScreenFromManifest(FlutterActivity.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.provideSplashScreen(FlutterActivity.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:518)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19382): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3736)
E/AndroidRuntime(19382):    ... 21 more
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(19610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19610): Process: lamrongol.date_interval_logger, PID: 19610
E/AndroidRuntime(19610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lamrongol.date_interval_logger/lamrongol.date_interval_logger.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3752)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1818)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.getSplashScreenFromManifest(FlutterActivity.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.provideSplashScreen(FlutterActivity.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:518)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19610): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3736)
E/AndroidRuntime(19610):    ... 21 more
```

対象デバイスをChrome(web)にすると正常に起動します。
なお、Android Emulatorで作ったデバイスはなぜか候補に表示されません。
参考にしたページはこちらです。 https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive

Comment: 利用しているスマートフォンを教えていただけますか？

Comment: この手順をそのままやったのなら、問題は起きないです。。orz
環境の構築から、初めての人に教える資料をつくるつもりで1つ1つやったことをメモしながら進めていくと実は何かをすっ飛ばしていたりしていたなどよくあることです。例えばいただいた情報では「対象のプログラム」もはっきりしませんし、どういう環境か、OSは？など全くわかりません。端末の機種APIレベル、端末のOSのバージョンなど。。案外整理しようと記録していたらさらっと解決したりもするので。。

Comment: >利用しているスマートフォンを教えていただけますか？ Galaxy Note 3 と Galaxy S9で試しましたがダメでした

Comment: 手順は質問にも書いてあるように公式ドキュメント( https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive )に沿って行ったはずです。OSはWindows 10、AndroidのOSは5と10です。とりあえず再度手順のとおりにやってみることにします。